# In cellForRowAt, how can you ensure that only elements with the same 1st letter as the section title get included?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexing, didselectrowatindexpath

What happens right now:

`numberOfRowsInSection` correctly gets the number of rows in each section by using a dictionary of words with same starting letter as section heading. So Australia and Argentina go in section A.

Problem is that `didSelectRowAt` can't use that same dictionary to set the cell because well it needs to select a different part of the struct (so didSelect and the precursors of the dictionary are in the same struct)

So in `cellForRowAt`, I match it to didSelectRowAt, so that the didSelectRowAt works perfectly. Problem then is for each section, all alphabet elements are included, not only the ones with the same 1st letter as the section title.

So for A, it would include something like Australia, Argentina. For B it would include Australia, Argentina, Brazil. For C Australia, Argentina, Brazil, Canada. Instead it should only include Canada at C etc

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     var cell = UITableViewCell()
    let aveKey = sectionTitle[indexPath.section]
    if let aveValue = aveDict[aveKey] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = dropDownOptions[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  self.delegate.dropDownPressed(string: dropDownOptions1[indexPath.row])
    print(dropDownOptions[indexPath.row])
    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return aveDict[sectionTitle[section]]?.count ?? 0


}
```

Part B: The structure

```
   struct CountryCodeItem {
let prefix: String
let country: String
let dashy: String
var displayText: String {
    "\(prefix) \(country)"
}
}
    //in viewDidLoad
    
    button.dropView.dropDownOptions = countryCodes.map { $0.displayText }
    button.dropView.dropDownOptions1 = countryCodes.map { $0.prefix }
    button.dropView.dropDownOptions2 = countryCodes.map { $0.country}
```

Part C: The dictionary

```
func createAvengersDict() {
    for avenger in dropDownOptions2 {
        let firstLetterIndex = avenger.index(avenger.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        let avengerKey = String(avenger[..<firstLetterIndex])
        if var avengerValues = avengersDict[avengerKey] {
            avengerValues.append(avenger)
            avengersDict[avengerKey] = avengerValues
        } else {
            avengersDict[avengerKey] = [avenger]
        }                                      
    }
    avengerSectionTitles = [String](avengersDict.keys)
    
    avengerSectionTitles = avengerSectionTitles.sorted(by: { $0 < $1
    })
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [`Dictionary(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init). In the documentation there is even an example how to group by the first letter.

Comment: Why do you need to have 3 lists ? Your avedict should be an dict of arrays of CountryCodeItem. This way once you get section from title array, you use indexPath.row to get item in avedict[aveKwy] array. Then from this object you get code, detailText or name depending if you are in cellForRow or didSelectRow.